# returning all transactions within 30 days of first transaction in SQL

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to return a list of customer IDs with the sum of all payments that they made within 30 days of the first payment they ever made. I tried it as

```
select 
    P.CustomerID, 
    SUM(P.TransactionAmount) 
from Customer_Payments P 
where P.dDatePaymentReceived < date_add(min(P.dDatePaymentReceived), INTERVAL 30 DAY) 
group by P.iCustomerID;
```

but this won't work because I can't include a `min()` within `date_add` in the where clause. Is there an easy way around this?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please edit your question and add the schema of the table (the CREATE TABLE statement). You can get around the issue by joining to a sub-select of the table with a calculated column where you get the minimum date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll have to do a subquery to get that min() since otherwise you are crossing over different levels/timing of aggregation. So aggregate in your subquery to get you customer's min(dDatePaymentsReceived) using a correlated subquery, and then aggregate like you had planned in your main query.

```
select 
    P.CustomerID, 
    SUM(P.TransactionAmount) 
from Customer_Payments P 
where P.dDatePaymentReceived < date_add((SELECT min(P.dDatePaymentReceived) FROM Customer_Payments CP WHERE cp.Customer_id = p.CustomerID) , INTERVAL 30 DAY) 
group by P.iCustomerID;
```